# Second order RLC circuit problem about signs

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks, math

Consider this circuit. Which is a second order RLC circuit.

[image: RLC1]

The problem asks for value of \$\phi\$ from the initial conditions.

[image: RLC2]

I took the first derivative of the equation by hand but as you'd see signs doesn't match with the solution of the problem.

[image: RLC3]

How did they find this answer from the equation above?

I suppose they neglected the C term for simplicity for current equation.

**Update :**

After solving the other part of the problem which asks for A I recognised that the differentiation is correct. But the solution would be \$\phi = \tan^{-1}(-\frac{\alpha}{\omega_d})\$

Only I couldn't be sure whether one of the sides of the triangle could be \$-\alpha\$

[image: RLC4]

Answer (score 0):

If: -

$$\omega_d \sin (\phi) = \alpha\cos(\phi)$$ Then: -

$$\dfrac{\sin (\phi)}{\cos(\phi)} = \dfrac{\alpha}{\omega_d}$$

Or: -

$$\tan(\phi) = \dfrac{\alpha}{\omega_d}$$

Can you take it from here?